# r get list of first, first two, first three letters of each word in a vector

Tags: r, list, substr

I would like to transform each element of a vector into their first, first two, etc. letters and again receive a vector with the results:

Example:

```
vector2 <- c("nike", "adidas")
```

Result:

```
> term2
[1]  "n"    "ni"   "nik"  "nike" "a"    "ad"   "adi"  "adid"  "adida"  "adidas"
```

This works for nike only:

```
vector1 <- c("nike")
  n <- nchar(vector1)
    for(i in 1:n)
     {
      term2[i] = substr(vector1, 1,i)
     }
```

But what about

```
  vector2 <- c("nike", "adidas")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
substring(rep(vector2, nchar(vector2)), 1, sequence(nchar(vector2)))
# [1] "n"      "ni"     "nik"    "nike"   "a"      "ad"     "adi"    "adid"   "adida" 
#[10] "adidas"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with `mapply` and `sapply` in base R -

```
v <- c("nike", "adidas")

unlist(
  mapply(function(x, y) {
    sapply(1:y, function(a) substr(x, 1, a))
  }, v, nchar(v))
)

nike1    nike2    nike3    nike4  adidas1  adidas2  adidas3  adidas4  adidas5  adidas6 
 "n"     "ni"    "nik"   "nike"      "a"     "ad"    "adi"   "adid"   "adida"  "adidas"
```